# Select @ before values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select name in email

Example:

```
sample@gmail.com
```

From that, I want to select `'sample'` only.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for MS SQL Server. You can easily replicate this if you use any other RDBMS

```
declare @email varchar(100)
set @email='sample@gmail.com'
select substring(@email,1,charindex('@',@email)-1)
```

Comment: Great ... Thank You For Answer

Comment: Madhivanan, are there any tags that should be edited into the post, to make it clear what version of SQL this question and answer is for?

Comment: I added the tag sql server

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @email nvarchar(200) = 'sample@gmail.com'
select left(@email,charindex('@',@email,0)-1)
```